How should my ceiling fan's switch circuit be connected in this outlet box?
I went to replace a wall outlet and committed the Cardinal sin of not taking before pictures.
Now I'm trying to wire everything back up and need help. I've traced the wires and determined what goes to what so I've got that going for me.
My biggest issue is getting my ceiling fan/light combo working.
When connecting the hot wire to the load on the ceiling fan, and the neutral to the neutral on it the fan does indeed work. However, when doing this the switch controlling it doesn't do anything now. It's just live all the time.
The light switch box seems to be a switch loop of sorts, at least that's my guess.
Seeking some advice from you all here on what I'm missing.



With switch loops, the white is suppose(do not count on it) to be the always hot and the black is the switch hot.  Switch loops usually get the power from the ceiling fixture(light/fan) so the receptacle should be wired black to black/white to white.  Do you have the old receptacle to see if the little tabs between the screws are still on?  A picture of the fan wiring will help.

Yes the tabs on the old receptacle were in tact for both the hot and neutral sides. I also tested and there is no voltage for either of the wires in the switch box, so if I am understanding what you're saying if it was a switch loop one of those would have some current going to them?

Pictures of how the wires are connected to the fan will help/and where the switch wires come from.  Are you sure those wires at the receptacle go to where you marked, or are you guessing?  Maybe one of those cables go to the switch instead of another outlet?

Update: I connected the hot wire coming from the panel to the black load wire for the fan. I then connected the neutral wire from the panel to the neutral coming from the other outlet bundle and the fan powered on, but it still isnt being controlled by the light switch.
I tested and the black wire in the light switch box is getting the correct voltage, but the white wire is not getting anything. Which makes sense since it is disconnected. What am I missing?
https://i.postimg.cc/1tHMmWNL/20240910-154755.jpg

Is it panel to this outlet then to other outlet, or panel to other outlet to this outlet?  If the second, then the cable label "other" might be to switch.  Switch gets power from this outlet and then powers the fan.  Which is a rare circuit path, but one guess(do not try something on a guess), to why the switch is not working.

Yes, it is panel to this outlet then to other outlet. Here's an updated picture of what I have hooked up now and the secondary outlet is getting power as well as the fan, but the light switch is not doing anything in either position. It is getting 120 at the black load wire at the switch and when it's in the on position that is completing the circuit and getting 120 on the other wire as well but it's not having any effect on the fan.
https://i.postimg.cc/HWPH7QV1/20240910-173809.jpg

If you connected the panel and fan white and blacks together and the fan works and the switch does nothing then the switch isn’t in the circuit or the switch is shorted internally. From the outlet box the ceiling fan wires should go to the switch box first and then to the fan. The whites are then nutted together and the blacks connect to opposite side of the switch. If you only have only one set of wires in your switch box then the ceiling fan is wired wrong. Only the fan’s black is tied to the outlet and panel black. The ceiling fan white is only connected the white coming from the switch, the black from the switch then connects to the whites at the outlet box. The blacks apply constantl hot white the white switch the neutral on and off.

In the fan Box itself the fan blak ties to the out/panel black. The fan’s white ties only to the switch white and the switch black ties to the outlet/ panel black in the ceiling fan itself.

You are missing another black wire. The whites all tie together. The ceiling fan black great to the switch and another black should go from the other side of the switch and tie together with main power and outlet blacks. Make sure all the tips of the wires are even, hold the three together and let the wire nut twist them together tightly. Hold the wire nut and pull on each wire individually to make sure all are connected properly. If one is loose, try again. Depending on the wire gauge a yellow should do it for 14 gauge if it’s all 12 gauge then a red should work for 3 wires

Why would there be more than three black wires? What does "great to the switch" mean?

These wires are in cables, not conduit. Which means (a) by definition there will be the same number of blacks and whites, (b) you can't add additional wires except by replacing cables. Which means the wires that are already in this box are exactly the wires needed to make things work the way they worked before.
